# Journey Builder Engagement Splits on dynamic links

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, hyperlink

How do I know whether or not contacts are clicking links that are built with ampscript, like this:  `%%=RedirectTo(@store_link)=%%`

[image]

You'll notice in the image that the links that are shown are just the direct links that I have in my email footer.  And it doesn't show all the links I have in the email that are created with AmpScript.

Here's an example of a link: `<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@store_link)=%%" alias="SquadLocker"  style="background-co...`

Comment: Have you tired using Aliases?

Comment: I am using aliases.  Updating comment to show more of the code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [**the documentation**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/use_the_engagement_split_activity/), you can't use dynamic links for engagement splits.

> Note: Links containing personalization strings or AMPScript are not supported.

Comment: Must have missed that...thanks @Adam.  

Do we know if we can do some link masking?  Or can the additional parameters be contain ampscript and I can send them to a dynamic landing page?  That should probably be a separate topic.

Comment: -have you heard of anyone getting PHISH warnings on emails that are sent with RedirectTo?

Comment: Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: The quoted message seems to be absent from the link in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working from SFMC you could query the _click data view - build an automation and have a separate journey running for the "clickers".

```
Select 
SubscriberKey,
JobID,
URL,
TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
TriggeredSendCustomerKey
FROM _Click
WHERE URL like 'www.yourLinkgoeshere.com'
```

I found this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24840/how-to-search-contacts-using-wildcard-characters-in-salesforce) helpful for any wildcard characters.

Answer (score 1):

> pasting from [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/380026/journey-builder-engagement-split-with-dynamic-link/380037#380037) for better visibility.

You cannot select a CTA/Link which have personalization string/Ampscript.

There are many ways to overcome. Here is one of the approach.

1. Place the below code to temporarily redirect to a code resource from Email CTA.
   `href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(1234,'s',_subscriberKey))=%%"`
2. Use the code below to capture the clicks to a DataExtension and then redirect to your actual URL link.

```js
%%[
SET @subscriberkey = RequestParameter("s")

/* Marking as LINK clicked */
 UpsertData("TEST_YourDE_Name", 1,
      "AccountID", @subscriberkey ,
      "MyLinkClicked", "YES",
      "Clicked_DateTime", Now() )

Redirect(Concat("https://youractualURLlinkhere?subscriber=",@subscriberkey))
]%%
```

3. Connect the above `TEST_YourDE_Name` data extension to the Contact model, using any attribute group.
4. Use this Data Extension field `MyLinkClicked` in decision split, by choosing Contact data.

Here is the the overview architecture of the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to The Salesforce documentación the standard engagement splits in Journey Builder (which are based on contact behavior) **don’t work well with links that use AMPscript for personalization**. If your contact opens or clicks an email link that uses AMPscript, a standard engagement split can’t make use of that data to guide the next step in the journey.

But there is a way! And we cover everything you need to know in this module. With a combination of AMPscript and SQL, you can make a decision split (which uses contact information) perform like an engagement split. In other words, your journey can respond to customer engagement—regardless of the link type (as shown in this example).

See full documentation in [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/engagement-splits-in-journey-builder-using-ampscript/gather-your-tools):