# Journey Builder - Engagement split with dynamic link

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, dataextensions, einstein-recommendations

I'm creating a journey and I wanted to use a split engagement on people who have or have not clicked on a certain link. However, the link I wanted to track is unique to the individuals and gets pulled in from the DE associated with them. Currently the button is linking to a personalisation tag called %%renewal_link%% which will get populated when sent out.

Therefore, I can't select it when setting up the split engagement. Is there anyway around this or alternative way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: There’s a whole trailhead explaining this: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/engagement-splits-in-journey-builder-using-ampscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You cannot select a CTA/Link which have personalization string/Ampscript.

There are many ways to overcome. Here is one of the approach.

1. Place the below code to temporarily redirect to a code resource from Email CTA.
   `href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(1234,'s',_subscriberKey))=%%"`
2. Use the code below to capture the clicks to a DataExtension and then redirect to your actual URL link.

```js
%%[
SET @subscriberkey = RequestParameter("s")

/* Marking as LINK clicked */
 UpsertData("TEST_YourDE_Name", 1,
      "AccountID", @subscriberkey ,
      "MyLinkClicked", "YES",
      "Clicked_DateTime", Now() )

Redirect(Concat("https://youractualURLlinkhere?subscriber=",@subscriberkey))
]%%
```

3. Connect the above `TEST_YourDE_Name` data extension to the Contact model, using any attribute group.
4. Use this Data Extension field `MyLinkClicked` in decision split, by choosing Contact data.

Here is the the overview architecture of the solution.

[image]